# Expected '^169.254$' to be /^169.254$/ in jasmine unit testing

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am new to Angular, Karma, Jasmine test framework. I am getting the following error. It was working fine. After upgrade to angular 7, I am getting the below error.

> [1A[2K[31mElectron 2.0.2 (Node 8.9.3) HostComponent should call
>   ipAddressPattern and check IP bad IP FAILED[39m   Expected '^169.254$'
>   to be /^169.254$/.
>         at 
>         at UserContext.it (karma-test-shim.js:298475:34418)
>         at ZoneDelegate../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke
>   (karma-test-shim.js:295054:26)
>         at ProxyZoneSpec../node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke
>   (karma-test-shim.js:294539:39)
>         at ZoneDelegate../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke
>   (karma-test-shim.js:295053:52)
>         at Zone../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (karma-test-shim.js:294813:43)
>         at runInTestZone (karma-test-shim.js:294104:34)
>         at UserContext. (karma-test-shim.js:294119:20)
>         at

My code is given below.

In unit test

```
it("should call ipAddressPattern and check IP bad IP", () => {
    expect(component.ipAddressPattern("169.254.11.11")).toBe(new RegExp(CommonConstants.BAD_IP_ADDRESS_PATTERN));
  });
```

Earlier code was like this `expect(component.ipAddressPattern("169.254.11.11")).toBe(CommonConstants.BAD_IP_ADDRESS_PATTERN);` and it was working. After upgrade it gave compilation issue. So I changed to `expect(component.ipAddressPattern("169.254.11.11")).toBe(new RegExp(CommonConstants.BAD_IP_ADDRESS_PATTERN))`
In the common constant class, the code is given below.

```
public static readonly BAD_IP_ADDRESS_PATTERN: string = "^169\.254$";
```

In other classes, the code is given below.

```
public ipAddressPattern(ipAddress: string): RegExp {
    return CommonUtil.isBadIPAddress(ipAddress);
  }
```

In CommonUtil class, the code is given below.

```
public static isBadIPAddress(ipAddress: string): any {
        if (ipAddress) {
            if (ipAddress.startsWith(CommonConstants.BAD_IP_ADDRESS)) {
                return CommonConstants.BAD_IP_ADDRESS_PATTERN;
            } else {
                return ValidationPatterns.IP_ADDRESS;
            }
        }
    }
```

Please suggest me how to fix this issue.

Comment: There's a difference between _"starts with"_ and _"is exactly"_. And you have to escape special characters in the string (why is it a string at all?) that you pass to `new RegExp()`.

Comment: Sir, this code `ipAddress.startsWith(CommonConstants.BAD_IP_ADDRESS)` is written by very senior JS developer, I have to fix only unit test case part.

Comment: Earlier code was like this `expect(component.ipAddressPattern("169.254.11.11")).toBe(CommonConstants.BAD_IP_ADDRESS_PATTERN);` and it was working. After upgrade it gave compilation issue. So I changed to `new RegExp()`.

Comment: `new RegExp() === new RegExp()` is `false`. You should remove the call to `new RegExp()`

Comment: So how should I fix it, please suggest? My job is to fix only the unit test case only.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the call to `new RegExp()`. That's going to return a new `RegExp` object each time, causing the test to fail.

To fix the compilation error, you need to correct the return type of `ipAddressPattern`. You're **not** returning a `RegExp` object, you're returning a `string`.

So the signature needs to be: `public ipAddressPattern(ipAddress: string): string`

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, the `String.prototype.startsWith` method (@line 3 in your `CommonUtil` class) is expecting a raw string, not a regex (in string format).

`expect(component.ipAddressPattern("169.254.11.11").toString()).toBe(new RegExp(CommonConstants.BAD_IP_ADDRESS_PATTERN).toString().replace(/^\/|\/$/g, ''))`

Comment: This will break the test (again)

Comment: Just replace the following sequence:

`if (ipAddress.startsWith(CommonConstants.BAD_IP_ADDRESS))`

with

`if (ipAddress.startsWith("169.254"))`

Comment: I can not change the constant class, I have to change only the unit test case.

Comment: Ok, then replace in your test:

`expect(component.ipAddressPattern("169.254.11.11")).toBe(new RegExp(CommonConstants.BAD_IP_ADDRESS_PATTERN));`

with

`expect(component.ipAddressPattern("169.254.11.11")).toBe(new RegExp(CommonConstants.BAD_IP_ADDRESS_PATTERN).toString().replace(/^\/|\/$/g, ''));`

Comment: After doing, I am getting error as `Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Expected<RegExp>'.`

Comment: Please test:

`expect(component.ipAddressPattern("169.254.11.11").toString()).toBe(new RegExp(CommonConstants.BAD_IP_ADDRESS_PATTERN).toString())` (makes more sense in the comment `new RegExp() === new RegExp()` is false. This if the final answer I guess

Comment: I tried with your edited answer, still I am getting the same error as `Expected '^169.254$' to be /^169.254$/`

Answer (score 0):

When I added `"@types/jasmine": "^2.8.7",`, in devDependencies, the problem got solved.
So I did like this.

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.46",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.7",
    ... other modules ...
}
```